# Could not resolve host error

Tags: networking, arch-linux, dns, dhcp

I'm using Arch Linux and I have a dynamic ip address with the use of dhcpcd. I can access websites through the google chrome but the problem is that I get 'could not resolve host' error when I run some commands on the terminal (like git clone).

I've tried pinging github.com and doing nslookup and it returns the correct ip. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Resolv.conf)?

Comment: @dcmst Cool, works fine now. You should post that as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that sometimes `dhcpcd`or other processes overwrite the content of the `resolv.conf` file, which is where DNS library resolver configuration is stored, inserting the DNS servers from your internet service provider, which may not work in some cases.

In case of problems it may be a good idea to change the content of `resolv.conf` to point to Open DNS servers (which should work better than your service provider servers):

```
# OpenDNS servers
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

or

```
# Google nameservers
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and then protect the content of resolv.conf from `dhcpcd` adding the line `nohook resolv.conf` to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`
See the mighty Arch [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Resolv.conf#Preserve_DNS_settings) for more details

Comment: @beefjerky, you're welcome, maybe [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71342/cant-access-some-websites) was actually caused by the same DNS problem?

Comment: Yup, it was the same issue. I'm closing it.